# Establecer tiempo de conexión JDBC

Tags: android, jdbc

Estoy con un proyecto en Android, el cual se conecta a una base de datos, a través de `JDBC`, tengo el problema, de que cuando inicio una actividad, esta carga datos de mi base de datos y el error que logro identificar es que tarda mucho en determinar si la conexión es nula y/o limitada, por ende, me gustaría poder establecer el tiempo máximo de conexión de esta (establecerlo en segundos), a continuación colocare el código que actualmente estoy usando

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Valoraraciones extends AppCompatActivity{
    Connection con;
    Spinner ruta;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    Button Boton;
    String ip,db,un,passwords;
    RatingBar rb;
    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_valoraraciones);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CicloMapp");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Boton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        rb=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

         ip = "mssql4.gear.host";
         db = "ciclomapp1";
         un = "ciclomapp1";
         passwords = "Mk36-9DX-580";
        ruta = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        String query = "select nombre from Rutas";
        try {
            con = connectionclass(un, passwords, db, ip);
            if (con == null) {
                Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Conexion a Internet perdida",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString("nombre");
                data.add(id);
            }
            String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
            ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
            ruta.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
            con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha producido un error, vuelva a intentarlo mas tarde",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String descripcion=et.getText().toString();
                String mail = getIntent().getExtras().getString("correo");
                String nRuta=ruta.getSelectedItem().toString();
                float rbv=rb.getRating();
                String query="insert into valorar values(next value for seq_valorar,'"+mail+"','"+nRuta+"',"+rbv+",GETDATE(),'"+descripcion+"');";
                try {
                    con = connectionclass (un, passwords, db, ip);
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    con.close();
                    Toast.makeText(Valoraraciones.this,"Ruta valorada con Exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server +"/"+ database + ";user=" + user+ ";password=" + password + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        }
        catch (SQLException se)
        {
            Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la documentación del driver que estas usando podrías darte una idea de lo que necesitas como podría ser socketTimeout que es el tiempo máximo de espera del socket. Para el caso de JTDS es tiempo en segundos.

Quedando tu url así:

```
int socketTimeout=600;
ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server +"/"+ database + ";user=" + user+ ";password=" + password + ";"+";socketTimeout="+socketTimeout+";";
```

En driver manager puedes setear el tiempo de login

```
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(Segundos);
```

Y para el resultado del query en el PreparedStatement

```
PreparedStatement preparedstatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
preparedstatement.setQueryTimeout(Segundos);
```

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Y no se que tan seguro sea por aquello de puertos en telefonía celular acceder a la base de datos de forma remota, te recomendaría más usar un webservice entre la base de datos y tu aplicación en android.